# If gem is installed in vendor/gems, why would Rails (2.3.4) complain that it is missing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have the `RedCloth` gem in my `vendor/gems` directory.

I also have this in my `environment.rb`:

```
config.gem 'RedCloth'
```

So why does Rails complain that the gem is missing:

```
Missing these required gems: 
RedCloth
```

What else does it need to recognize that I have it installed in the `vendor/gems` directory?

`environment.rb`:

```
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.4' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'boot')

Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  config.gem 'RedCloth'
  config.plugins = [ :all ]
  config.action_controller.session_store = :active_record_store
  config.time_zone = 'UTC'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because config.gem try require 'RedCloth', but you need require 'redcloth'

```
config.gem 'RedCloth', :lib => 'redcloth'
```

Comment: @chuck, that's what I told you in another post, also, you would still need 'rake gems:build' if you unpacked the gem in vendor/gems

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Rails 3 then you need to specify it in the `Gemfile`.

Comment: You can use Gemfile with Rails 2.2.x too

Answer (score 1):

```
rake gems:build
```